# iptables ACCEPT policy

Tags: linux, security, iptables

In Redhat EL 6,
iptables INPUT policy is `ACCEPT`
but INPUT chain has REJECT entry in the end. `/etc/syconfig/iptables` is as below:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Do you know why the policy is `ACCEPT` not `DROP`?
I think setting `DROP` policy is safer than `ACCEPT`
in case to make mistake in the chain.
Actually the policy is not applied to any packet:

```
# iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

The policies affect what happens when traffic is not "caught" by any other rule.

`DROP` policy is a good idea if you are hardening your server.  It is probably not like that by default because there's no way for the distribution maintainers to know how you'll use the system or what services you'll have active on the system in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since the last rule in the chain matches all packets, the default policy isn't ever used. Using a catch all rule to reject remaining traffic allows the reject method to be selected, and is also more obvious when looking at `iptables -nvL` output. You could change it to REJECT or DROP if you wanted, but it's not going to change the behaviour.